# Detect no apps running on foreground android

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a simple android apps which will show some kind of popup if no apps currently running on foreground / visible on screen (except my own apps). So how can I detect if there is no apps currently running on screen?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the app that is in the foreground:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
    if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
        Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
    }
}
```

Then simply compare `appProcess.processName` to the package name of the launcher on the device, which you can get using:

```
private String findLauncherPackageName(){       
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    final ResolveInfo res = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0); 
    Log.e("ANDRO_ASYNC", String.format("findLauncherPackageName()%s",res.activityInfo.packageName));
    return res.activityInfo.packageName;
}
```