# React-Native Detect App running on Foreground

Tags: android, react-native

How do you go about detecting what app is currently running on the foreground when using react-native.

My RN app will be running in the background and needs to be able to detect the launch of specific apps within the phone. For example if the user opens game, how would i go about detecting what the app opened is (app package id).

I read that android native has this feature, through reading this stack overflow question [detect apps running in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919283/detect-no-apps-running-on-foreground-android)

I would like to know if there is a process similar in react-native, help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "I read that android native has this feature" -- not in the past few years, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare so is there no way of doing this task??

Comment: Are you trying to detect other apps that you have built?